# Python - Add a tuple to an existing list of tuples in a specific position

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

Suppose I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
listA = [ (B,2), (C,3), (D,4) ]
```

I would like to add another tuple `(E,1)` to this list. How can I do this?

And more specifically, I would like to add this tuple as the 1st tuple in the list so that I get:

```
newList = [ (E,1), (B,2), (C,3), (D,4) ]
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listA.insert(index, item)
```

For you:

```
listA.insert(0, ('E', 1))
```

If you want it in your new variable, assign it AFTER inserting (thanks TigerHawk)

```
newList = listA
```

Important thing to remember, as well - as Padraic Cunningham pointed out - this has it so both lists are referencing the same object.  If you change listA, you'll change newList.  You can make a new object by doing some other things:

```
newList = listA[:]
newList = list(listA)
```

Comment: `newList` is now `None` because `insert()` modifies the original `list`.

Comment: Crap, you're right.  insert() has a return value of `None`.  Gotta assign it _after_ the insertion if you want it in a new variable!

Comment: You now have a reference to listA so any changes in listA will affect newList.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to be appending to the beginning a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) would be a more efficient structure:

```
from collections import deque

deq = deque([("B",2), ("C",3), ("D",4) ])

deq.appendleft(("E",1))

print(deq)
deque([('E', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4)])
```

appending to the start of the deque is `0(1)`.

If you actually wanted a new list and to keep the old you can simply:

```
newList = [(E,1)] + listA
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to beginning of this you just do

`listA.insert(0, (E,1))`.

Insert adds to a specific index of a list.

Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html